# How to convert CString to CByteArray?

Tags: c++, mfc, cstring

I know that converting `CByteArray` to `CString` is pretty straightforward. But how do I do it the other way around - from `CString` to `CByteArray`?

Answer (score 4):

GetBuffer() method of the CString class returns the array you need. After that you can copy it using the memcpy or other similar function to a CByteArray object.

```
CString csData = L"someData";
CByteArray byteArr;

BYTE *pByteArray = (PBYTE)(LPCTSTR)csData.GetBuffer();
byteArr.SetSize(csData.GetLength());

memcpy(byteArr.GetData(), pByteArray, csData.GetLength());
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to take into account, that 1 character in a `CString` is usually not 1 byte.

```
const size_t noBytes = sizeof(CString::XCHAR) * myString.GetLength();
byteArray.SetSize( noBytes );
std::memcpy( 
    byteArray.GetData(),
    reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(myString.GetBuffer()), 
    noBytes );
```

So you need to consider if this is really the intended behaviour.